# Another way instead SNMP

Tags: monitoring, snmp

Is there an other way of monitoring the system threshold values (RAM, CPU) instead of SNMP?
There should be as simple way as client-server interaction since defining TRAP in SNMP is not easy at the beginning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SNMP Traps are not the only way to get these values with SNMP.  You could use an SNMP GET for RAM / CPU / Disk

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're quering a Windows machine you can use [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation). It is really powerfull and there is also a Linux porting if you are quering from a Linux machine. For example if you want to monitor RAM usage you can execute the following query:

```
select FreePhysicalMemory from Win32_OperatingSystem
```

Now if you want more information I need to know your platform system and what language you will use.

Comment: Platform : RedHat Linux, Programming Language: Java